# SQL EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MYDATE) not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table `MYTABLE` with columns `mydate` and `quantity` of `VARCHAR2` type.

```
|mydate|   |quantity|
10/15/2010     15
01/20/2010     20
05/16/2005     30
04/29/2005     50
03/30/2008     5
```

I want to get:

```
|year|   |quantity|
  2010         35
  2005         80
  2008          5
```

I try:

```
SELECT 
    to_char(mydate,'yyyy') YEAR, 
    SUM(to_number(quantity)) 
FROM MYTABLE 
GROUP BY 
    to_char(mydate,'yyyy');
```

But I get an error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

What did I do wrong?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have a date - it should be a **Date** or **DateTime** datatype. If you have a *quantity*, it should be a **numeric** datatype!

Comment: AH, i found my error, i made ORDER BY mydate, not by to_char(mydate,'yyyy') and because of that got error.

Answer (score 0):

You must put all columns of the SELECT in the GROUP BY or use functions on them which compress the results to a single value (like MIN, MAX or SUM).

A simple example to understand why this happens: Imagine you have a database like this:

```
FOO BAR
0   A
0   B
```

and you run SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY foo. This means the database must return a single row as result with the first column 0 to fulfill the GROUP BY but there are now two values of bar to chose from. Which result would you expect - A or B? Or should the database return more than one row, violating the contract of GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    select extract(year from mydate),sum(to_number(quant)) from mytable
group by extract(year from mydate);
```

**[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d31dd/3)**